# Profile for Drupal User Registration not functioning

Tags: drupal, user-account

Our simple "My Details" profile for Drupal User Registration is not functioning.

The profile adds fields for First Name, Last Name and Birth Date to the Drupal User Registration page.

But when a new user registers, an account is created but the profile field information is not saved. Even the field names (mostly) are not shown on the new users page (see second image below). A Civi contact is created with just the Drupal email address.

Even if admin user tries to add those details via the Drupal user page, the information is not saved. If added via CiviCRM, the contact information does appear in the Drupal accounts.

I've tried creating a new registration profile with just First and Last Name and disabling the existing one - same result.

We have latest Civi version 4.7.25 and Drupal 7.56. No errors in Drupal logs at time of account creation. Several modules including Mollom, Webform-Civi Integration, Civi-Rules Integration, LoginToboggan, Views etc. installed.

Any suggestions on how we can debug this appreciated!

Phil Hart - Camp Cooinda - CiviCRM Member

[image: User with correct details]
[image: User when profile not working]

Comment: So logged out I go to https://campcooinda.asn.au/user/register and i see the fields. but you are saying that if i submit the form these details are not added to civi? There was a console error for me about register:205 GET https://rest-production.mollom.com/v1/captcha/171014761ce5e6f12f.png net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT - but that might have been Privacy Badger at my end. I popped through a user/account - hope that was okay ;-)

Comment: Correct Pete. In this case the Civi contact wasn't even created. It's a pretty basic function that's not working for us. Would happily give your new account admin privilege if you want a look. we are webmaster@campcooinda.asn.au

Comment: Hey Phil - would be good if you put the answer up if you have it to hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We engaged Fuzion to resolve this, who systematically disabled all modules to find the offending one.

The issue was caused by the Page Manager module, which was overriding the user/%/edit pages (admin/structure/pages). This override was empty, and I'm unsure why it was enabled - but by disabling it the civicrm profile forms are fixed. This also resolves the issue we were observing where an administer role was being removed upon submitting this form.

One further step was required, which was to disable a redirect to the webform we had in place after a new user was created (configured here: admin/structure/trigger/user). It appears what was happening is that the redirect is stepping in after the user is created, but before CiviCRM had time to react to the new information.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Drupal CiviCRM permissions, particularly the following:

- CiviCRM: profile create (anonymous users)
- CiviCRM: access all custom data (anonymous and authenticated users)
- CiviCRM: profile edit (authenticated users)

Also, check the profile settings: click "fields" and make sure none of them are "view only".

Answer (score 0):

Have found something for you in Google to start from, not sure if it helps, yet, you may want to to have a look:

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/users-contacts/

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=30064.0 (form year 2013)

https://www.google.com/search?q=civicrm+drupal+profile+sync (if anything else fails)

Comment: Thanks for trying. Have read through a fair bit of info like that but not been able to find anything that identifies our issue. It's pretty basic functionality that is not working for us at the moment but hard to troubleshoot.